# Converting from actionscript 3 to html canvas in flash cc 2015 setTimeout nextFrame

Tags: actionscript-3, html5-canvas, flash-cc

I'm converting an actionscript 3.0 file to html canvas in flash cc. Is there a way to convert this code:

```
setTimeout(frameNineDelay,4500)

function frameNineDelay(){
nextFrame();
}
```

Comment: I think you should be more clear on your question...

Comment: You need this.nextFrame(); "this" is necessary in most cases when dealing with createJS